# For loop not storing the results in for-purpose data frame columns

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, predict

I have created the below for loop to deal with a prediction process on panel data. While each procedure on the data works like a charm, the storage of the predictions (last step) is unsuccessful. Due to incompetence on my part (fairly new to for loops), the for loop is not replacing the NAs in the data frame columns created for storage with the numeric predictions. What am i doing wrong?

There are 17 prefectures, each having 61 observations. Therefore, for each, i get 61 predictions.

Data set used: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/v2xk34ac58h2kk7uxunat/dt1.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=gf2e15z4gtuu83lxalzn91rai

```
#Data prep for modeling and predictions
mydata$...1 <- NULL #remove useless column

mydata$month_year <- as.factor(mydata$month_year) #time fixed-effects

mydata$ncve_relax_lag <- as.numeric(mydata$ncve_relax_lag) #make numeric
mydata$ncve_strict_lag <- as.numeric(mydata$ncve_strict_lag)

mydata <- mydata %>% drop_na()

mydata$population <- mydata$population/10000 #scaling

mydata$area <- mydata$area/10000 #scaling
    
mydata$no_troops <- mydata$no_troops/1000 #scaling

#Create data frame columns to store predictions
mydata$nbpred.core <- NA
mydata$nbpred.lit <- NA
mydata$nbpred.base <- NA

#Model fitting and predictions
runPredictions <- function(){
  for(i in unique(mydata$prefecture)){
    print(i)
    
    #Define training and test sets
    sptllearningSet <- mydata[mydata$prefecture != i,]
    sptltestSet <- mydata[mydata$prefecture == i,]
    
    #Train model
    sptlnb_base <- glm.nb(ncve_relax ~ population + 
                           capdist +
                           month_year,
                           data = sptllearningSet,
                           control = glm.control(maxit = 3000))
    
    
    sptlnb_lit <- glm.nb(ncve_relax ~ population + 
                          capdist + 
                          multidim.poverty +
                          eth_frc_t13 +
                          eth_plr_t13 +
                          sp_lag_relax +
                          ncve_relax_lag +
                          month_year,
                          data = sptllearningSet,
                          control = glm.control(maxit = 3000))
    
    
    sptlnb_core <- glm.nb(ncve_relax ~ population + 
                           capdist + 
                           multidim.poverty +
                           eth_frc_t13 +
                           eth_plr_t13 +
                           sp_lag_relax +
                           ncve_relax_lag +
                           no_troops +
                           unpol.dummy +
                           area +
                           ruggedness +
                           month_year, 
                           data = sptllearningSet,
                           control = glm.control(maxit = 3000))
    
    #Use coefficients to predict on test
    mydata$nbpred.core[mydata$prefecture == i] = as.numeric(predict(sptlnb_core, newdata = mydata[mydata$prefecture == i,], type='response'))
    mydata$nbpred.lit[mydata$prefecture == i] = as.numeric(predict(sptlnb_lit, newdata = mydata[mydata$prefecture == i,], type='response'))
    mydata$nbpred.base[mydata$prefecture == i] = as.numeric(predict(sptlnb_base, newdata = mydata[mydata$prefecture == i,], type='response'))
  }
}
```

Thank you for the help!

EDIT: I've added the initial part of my code to ensure it is fully reproducible.

Comment: Can you provide an example data set so we can provide better help?

Comment: Have you considered some version of `pmap` functions? They can assign each value of the loop to a row in a dataframe, for example. Then you could chain them together.

Comment: @BrianFisher done. Sorry about that. Should have done it straight away.

Comment: @CareyCaginalp i haven't. How would that work in this case? I've never used pmap functions or the purrr package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dealing with a scoping issue, when you are running your for loop inside the function, the predictions are getting assigned within the function, but not affecting the global environment where the data frame is accessible.

The most straightforward method to handle this is just to pull the for loop out of the function - delete the call `runPredictions <- function(){}` and it should work fine.
Alternatively, you could force the function to assign to the global envoronment, or apply the individual functions across the prefectures (e.g. using pmap)

Comment: Thank you very much @BrianFisher. That solved it.